# Why doesn't my js for loop have any output?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to debug my code.
When I add `console.log('aaa');` it shows ok in the test output

When I add `console.log` statements within a `for` loop however

```
console.log('aaa');
for(let i = 0; i++; i < 10) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

I get the 'aaa' as output but I do not get the numbers in the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  - for(let i = 0;  i < 10; i++)

Comment: omg I thought I had stopped making this mistake a long ago THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop should have the check *before* the increment

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                ^       ^
               switch these
```